# Unix Error: Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Tags: unix, sudoers

I am trying to add a particular user in the group using command: sudo usermod -a -G groupname username.
but getting error as "Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported".

I dont have any idea about sudoers file. Can anybody please help me on this.

Comment: There is a file called `/etc/sudoers` in Unix, You cannot achieve modification of user, unless you're(your username) in the sudoers list, with permissions granted to you.

Comment: This question is quite [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. Should be a better fit for [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: This is also trivially [googleable](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Username+is+not+in+the+sudoers+file.+This+incident+will+be+reported&oq=Username+is+not+in+the+sudoers+file.+This+incident+will+be+reported&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.219j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) which leads you straight to [another stackexchange site](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151200/my-main-username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file)

Answer (score 0):

The config file `/etc/sudoers` lists the users who are allowed to run which commands as which user.

On Ubuntu, this file contains a line allowing all users of the `sudo` group to run commands as the `root` user.

To check which users are in the `sudo` group you can type `getent group sudo`. You can also check the groups of your current user by typing `id`.

To allow another user to run `sudo`, you can add them to the `sudo` group:

```
sudo adduser username sudo
```

Or, if your current user can't run `sudo`, you will need to boot into "Recovery mode" from Grub (hold `shift` while booting, if your grub menu doesn't show up automatically), or add `single` to the `linux ... initrd ... quiet splash` line, then:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
adduser username sudo
```

Run `adduser` for each user you want to be able to `sudo`. Then exit & resume.